# MySql LEFT JOIN ON (First 6 letters)

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to `LEFT JOIN` and use only 6 letters in `ON`?

Here's my code.

```
 SELECT 
    b.UID
 FROM master_listing AS a
 LEFT JOIN courier_information AS b ON LEFT(a.remarks, 6) = b.courierCode
```

master_listing table

```
 id         remarks
  1         112233GOODAY
```

courier_information table

```
 id      courierCode   UID
  1         112233      27
```

Unfortunately my query above is not working, it returns NULL.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output when you do a `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT b.UID`? That may help you debug.

Comment: LEFT is going to return a string and my guess is couriercode is not a string?  So  you need to transform `LEFT(a.remarks, 6)` to the same data type as courier code.  Try Cast?

Comment: @Pang same result NULL, But when I just use `a.remarks  = b.courierCode` in `ON` its working.

Comment: @MageeWorld I don't think its on datatype, they are both char. I think LEFT(a.remarks, 6) is not valid to use in `ON`.

Comment: What happens if you make it a right join instead of a left join - or an inner join - why are you using a left join?

Comment: Do the first six letters always form a number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A NULL value would be the expected return for `b.anycolumn` from the **`a LEFT JOIN b`** operation, when there is no "matching" row found in `b`. (The rows from `a` will be returned, and MySQL will return NULL values for all columns from `b`.)

It looks like you are asking why the row from `b` isn't being matched; why the comparison test isn't returning TRUE for any rows.

What you've omitted is the *datatype* of the `courierCode` column.

Given that a query with the condition **`a.remarks = b.courierCode`** does find a matching row, and given that we are shown example value in the `remarks` column as  `'112233GOODAY'`, we surmise that the `remarks` column is character type.

We can also conclude that the comparison is *not* on character string values.

Evaluated in a numeric context, the string value `'112233GOODAY'` is going to be interpreted as numeric value, of `112233`. So we know that there is an implicit datatype conversion occurring, the `remarks` is being converted to numeric.  That same conversion should be happening on the return from the `LEFT()` function.

Demonstration setup:

```
  CREATE TABLE master_listing 
  ( id          INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
  , remarks     VARCHAR(12) 
  );
  INSERT INTO master_listing (id, remarks)
  VALUES (1,'112233GOODAY');

  CREATE TABLE courier_information 
  ( id          INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
  , couriercode INT UNSIGNED 
  , uid         INT UNSIGNED 
  );
  INSERT INTO courier_information (id, couriercode, uid)
  VALUES (1,112233,27);
```

Demonstration query:

```
  SELECT b.UID
    FROM master_listing a
    LEFT
    JOIN courier_information b 
      ON LEFT(a.remarks, 6) = b.courierCode
  ;
```

Output as expected:

```
     UID  
  ------
      27
```

There's something going on that you haven't revealed. I've made assumptions about the datatypes of the columns.

My guess (just a guess) is that there is a leading space in the `remarks` column.

For debugging this, output additional columns to inspect the values...

```
  SELECT a.id
       , a.remarks
       , LEFT(a.remarks,6)
       , HEX(a.remarks)
    FROM master_listing a
   WHERE a.id = 1
```

If the `remarks` value has a leading space, then the `LEFT(remarks,6)` will evaluate to `' 11223'`, and compared in a numeric context, that is not equal to `112233`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CONVERT(LEFT(a.remarks,6), UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```